# I have 2 index.html files in django project, how to show direct separately

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 index.html files in django project, but in different apps. How can i show direct separately for each of them?

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

create the following folder structure

```
- app1
-- templates
--- app1
---- index.html
- app2
-- templates
--- app2
---- index.html
```

then in your views.py for app1

```py
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'app1/index.html')
```

That folderstructure is called namespacing. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) the section "Template namespacing"